# Can we re-open this?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close

Can we act on [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183177/openvpn-kill-switch-on-linux)?

The question basically asks how to set up a firewall on Linux that blocks non VPN connections.

Would a rewording of the question be useful in order to re-open it?

Can we move it to Server Fault / Super User and re-open it?

I also note that a lot of questions on SE explicitly asking "how to do this with openvpn" stays open. See for example [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167828/dns-leak-with-vpnbook-openvpn?rq=1) asking "how can I still change the DNS [using openvpn]".

Only the question in subject got closed.

Comment: Please use the voting buttons on the question to vote to reopen. Are those controls available to you?

Comment: "only this question got closed" -- that's not true at all. Lots of closed questions get deleted and flushed.

Comment: @schroeder no I have no re-open button

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it has been so long that migration is not possible.

It was not closed for being off-topic but because it was lacking details and the OP never responded.